# Collect the data in the database column

Tags: php, mysql

DB Table 1

```
ID  -  Name   -   Quantity   -   Price  -  Date
1      Jack       100            10        07-03-2017
2      Justine    120            12        07-03-2017
3      Jack       150            15        07-03-2017
4      Justine    200            20        07-03-2017
6      Jack       10             1         06-03-2017
```

DB Table 2 (Result)

```
ID  -  Name   -   Quantity   -   Price  -  Date
1      Jack       250            25        07-03-2017
2      Justine    220            22        07-03-2017
6      Jack       10             1         06-03-2017
```

I have DB Table 1. I want to collect the prices of the same name and date in DB Table 1. How can i ?  // PHP & Mysql

Comment: Why 1,2,6 and not 3,4,6?

Comment: What have you done so far?

Answer (score 0):

Try this query.

```
SELECT name, SUM(quantity), SUM(price), date FROM db1 GROUP BY name, date
```

Comment: Is it in the Php department or is it in the mysql department  ?

Comment: Hi, I am giving him/her the sql command to get the results, you can use the above command either in phpmyadmin, mysql cli or in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following query to achieve your desired result:

```
SELECT `id`,`name`, SUM(`quantity`), SUM(`price`), `date` FROM `db1` GROUP BY `name`, `date`
```

Answer (score 0):

> **Please note that stackoverflow is not a tutorial website, we are not here to teach you how to code but to help you with a particular coding
>   problem you are facing in your existing code**

if you can google php mysql tutorials you gonna get thousands of results too choose from, atleast show some effort that you have tried to figure this by yourself. with that being said, here's how you can achieve this :

you have two ways to achieve your desired results ;

1. use mysqli

   the php.net manual is always a good start http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php   everything, every function of mysqli is available from there.

2 Use PDO,
  also most if not everything you need to know is available in the manual : http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

you can also follow this blog, covers most of the important aspects: https://phpdelusions.net/pdo

back  to your question,

> I assume you know how to create database and tables so I wont waste
>   time on that .

you need to create a connection with php that will communicate with your database, by the way I'm using PDO.

**db.config.php**

```
<?php
$host    = '127.0.0.1';
$db      = 'test';
$user    = 'root';
$pass    = '';
$charset = 'utf8';

$dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=$charset";
$opt = [
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
        PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
        PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
        ];


$dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $opt);
?>
```

then a page to do the queries on, so i create index page

**index.php**

```
<?php
include'db.config.php'; //calling the database file



$stmt = $dbh->query("SELECT `id`,`name`, SUM(`quantity`) as quantity, SUM(`price`) as price, `date` FROM `test` GROUP BY `name`, `date`")->fetchAll();

echo "<table border=\"1\">";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<th>ID</th>";
echo "<th>Name</th>";
echo "<th>Quantity</th>";
echo "<th>Price</th>";
echo "<th>Date</th></tr>";
foreach ($stmt as $row) {

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['quantity'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['price'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['date'] . "</td>";


}

?>
```

**results :**

[image]

That's all, hope this will help and please follow tutorials on the internet.

**NB: Don't get used to getting full code done for you that's not how SO works.**